# Encoding audio file to base64 in Flutter

Tags: flutter, base64, dialogflow-es

I'm developing an app using Flutter that implementing Dialogflow api. I want to add voice recognation feature but the Dialogflow api only accept audio file in base64 format. I'm stuck at encoding the audio file. Please help me I'm new to Flutter.

**This is the error:**
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/book_a_room.wav' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

```
String path = 'assets/book_a_room.wav';
  Future<String> Base64(String path) async {
    try {
      File file = File(path);
      file.openRead();
      List<int> fileBytes = await file.readAsBytes();
      String base64String = base64Encode(fileBytes);
      return base64String;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: use `rootBundle.load(...)`, not `file.readAsBytes()`

Comment: I do still get an error..."The argument type 'ByteData' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<int>'."

Comment: `ByteData` has `buffer` property

Comment: I'm sorry but still didn't get the expected result...I use asInt64List() buffer method. Get this error "Invalid argument (Not a byte value at index 0: 0x794a46464952)"

Comment: tried another `asInt*List()` methods?

Comment: sure, your welcome